# User Settings Not Working When Deployed By Setup Project (C# VS2013) *FIXED

Tags: installation, settings

I have made a few setup projects in my time, but this is a first for using User Settings. I may be using the wrong "words" when searching since I cannot be the only person with this issue.

The user settings I am talking about, are the settings you define in the Project Properties -> Settings. They work like a charm inside VS, but when I make the installer (using the free setup project extension, not the WiseInstaller LE that is included) and run the EXE, nothing takes.

I tried including the settings.settings file, and the App.Config file but that idea did not work.

What am I doing wrong? If I need to convert these to registry entries, then I need to do a lot of recoding. These are scoped to User, not Application.

Thanks,

Dave

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it had nothing to do with the setup project, but rather my code flow. The settings form first tried to connect to the DB, since the connection information is entered on that form, it threw a cannot find error, so thinking that is what it should do, I hit continue. Well I was a bit wrong.

That error kind of made the form stop working since the information comes after the DB connection. I added a trap, and changed the code flow and all is good again.

Thanks

Dave